# Linking problems with TinyXml++ and Visual C++ Express Edition 2008

Tags: c++, linker, tinyxml++

I'm trying to use TinyXml++ in my project, and I have tested it successfully in a small program before. I recently decided to use it to read a configuration file in my current project and though the code compiled, I got a ton of linker errors (unresolved external symbols mostly). I read in some forum thread, describing a similar problem, that I had to use the same runtime library as TinyXml++ was compiled with. I opened the accompanying Visual C++ 2008 project and saw it was using Multi-threaded Debug (/MTd).

I have now tested all runtime libraries with and without #define TINYXML_USE_TICPP before I include "ticpp.h". I've gotten from 9 to 80 linker errors (which I why I initially didn't want to post them all, but I will if you want to see them).

I have copied the static library ticppd.lib (found in the download folder) to my project's directory and linked it under Linker->Input->Addtional Dependencies. I have included a directory path to the TinyXml++ source under C/C++->General->Addtional Include Directories. What am I doing wrong? :(

Answer (score 1):

TinyXML is a library with the full source code available; you should not need to include a .lib. You could separate TinyXML into a separate project and mark your project as depending on it, which will allow you to compile both projects with consistent settings for threading and debugging, but the easiest way to get it working should be to just add the TinyXML .cpp and .h files (just not the test one) to your project and compile.